# Samba server stopped working after some router changes

Tags: networking, server, samba

I installed ubuntu server with samba step-by-step with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndAYZ0DJ-U4.

I used samba on ubuntu server 14.04 for two days. Everything was fine, all my devices connected on network can access this server without problem. Then I move some files to server about 80GB. I can access this data from all devices. Then I shutdown server and change some router setting like password and coding (from tkip to aes).

When I wanted to start server again this shows up:

```
waiting for network configuration
```

followed by:

`waiting an additional 60 seconds for network configuration`

Since that happened no device can see server in network.

I tried to edit network interface:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Restore it to default setting and back to static ip again. After this changes I do not see the error message no more. But nothing else.

I checked samba config and restarted all services. - not helped

Please help.

Comment: I tried to reinstall samba, when I want to install it back I find out my server cant connect to internet. This information may be important.

Answer (score 1):

I am using samba server in home network as  mentioned below. If it stopped working you can try reinstalling it but most probably problem is in router settings. If you don't know what you changed in it then you have to reset it.

Install and Remove from the Terminal : (Using Samba Version 4.3.11)

---

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge samba
```

But, if you are having client problems, it would be more like:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge smbclient libsmbclient

sudo apt-get purge samba samba-common
sudo rm -rf /etc/samba/ /etc/default/samba
```

To install it again

```
sudo apt-get install samba
sudo apt-get install smbclient libsmbclient
```

---

How to Reinstall smb.conf in other way

```
dpkg-reconfigure samba-common
or
sudo cp -a /usr/share/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/
```

---

Restart Ubuntu after fresh installation and add user

---

```
root@Dell-Inspiron-3521:~# sudo smbpasswd -a username (username should be without space eg "sudo smbpasswd -a alamjitsingh")
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:*********
Added user alamjitsingh.*********
```

---

smb.conf required settings

---

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/samba/smb.conf


[global]
 workgroup = WORKGROUP
 passdb backend = tdbsam 
 security = user
```

In authentication section turn "map to guest = bad user" off by adding  # at starting of code

```
#map to guest = bad user
```

Below line is Optional if not working

```
force user = alamjitsingh
```

At last add your personal code

```
[Shared_drive_Name]
path = /media/alamjitsingh/Shared_drive_Name (alamjitsingh is my ubuntu username)
comment = HD Share
read only = yes
available = yes
browseable = yes
writable = no
guest ok = no
public = yes
printable = no
locking = no
strict locking = no
```

---

Useful Terminal commands

```
sudo service samba reload 
sudo service samba restar
sudo service samba stop
sudo service samba start
sudo service samba status
sudo service samba force-reload
```

Or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd start
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd stop
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart

sudo testparm

sudo service nmbd start
sudo service smbd start
```

Or (via systemctl)

```
sudo systemctl restart smbd
sudo systemctl start smbd
sudo systemctl restart nmbd
sudo systemctl start nmbd
```

Check status of required services

```
sudo service nmbd status
sudo service smbd status
sudo service smbd restart
```

To know version of samba

```
samba -V
```

---